# How to troubleshoot/resolve an issue with TTY when using php from command line breaks the TTY echo?

Tags: php, windows, shell, tty, mingw-w64

I am having the following issue:

In my MINGW64 window supplied by Git for Windows, when I type the following:

```
php --version
php script.php
php *anything*
```

I receive no command output.  Also, when I type anything after that, I do not see my input, but my input still counts.  i.e. when I enter a command, and press enter, it is still executed.  Looking at [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened) I see that it is an issue with TTY reset.  i.e. when I type `reset`, my terminal returns to normal.

My question is how to I fix it to where operational of the tty is normal and I don't have to type reset to return it to normal?

I have the following:

- Windows 10
- PHP 7.1.7 for Windows VC14 x64 Thread Safe (2017-Jul-06 19:58:21)
- Apache/2.4.27 (Win64)
- Git for Windows (2.13.3) 64-bit

I suspect it is an issue with the php executable, because when I do `git --version` it works fine.  It's the php that does not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works okay:

```
php-win --version
```

There is a "win" version of PHP.  Not sure how different it is from `php`, but perhaps the different `phps`have different purposes.